# 'social' is not a registered namespace

Tags: django

Im trying to implement google authentication but
I got the following error:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'social' is not a registered namespace
```

i have like this in my login.html:

```
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}"> Sign in with Google</a>
```

I also added this in my setting.py

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_URL_NAMESPACE = 'social'
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
    path('profile/', user_views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('login/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
 
]
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: What is the purpose of the identical `login/` urls?  The second one will always be ignored...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="{% url 'begin' 'google-oauth2' %}"> Sign in with Google</a>
```

**Updated**

Please fix the URL mapping conflict as mentioned by @John Gordon:

```
path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
path('login/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

You can't have two identical url patterns since Django finds the first one and then doesn't go further down the list if the first is a match. You can name it anything else such as 'accounts', 'users', you get the idea like so:

```
path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

Do this change then see what you get and report back. Also, please include the settings.py file with your question as a code section rather than a comment.

Comment: its not working

Comment: As @John Gordon mentioned, fix the url path conflict first. Then, please include the INSTALLED_APPS  list above so we know what's happening.

Comment: how to fix the url path conflict?

Comment: `
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',

]
`

Comment: @HelloKitty see the updated answer

Comment: hmm still the same error

Comment: @HelloKitty Do you have 'social:begin' used in any other places like the logout, navbar, or register templates? If yes, change it accordingly. If not, update the url pattern for the allauth like so: path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls'), namespace='social').

Comment: @HelloKitty  if tthis fixes it, please accept the answer and if there are other errors ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in urls.py where the url with namespace 'begin' has been defined, before url pattern

```
app_name = 'social'
```

Comment: its not working

Comment: Show the code where you have defined the url with begin namespace

Comment: i dont have define the url with begin namespace